# PHP Simple Time Check (hour)

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

Although I have been working with PHP for a while, the one part of it I am still trying to get right is time.

I am creating a simple script that will check if the `timestamp` is greater than or equal to an hour, and if it is, it will be deleted from the database.

```
2013-01-03 20:30:25

DELETE FROM tablename WHERE timestamp = ?????
```

I am not sure how to execute the query to delete values with a `timestamp` of over an hour from the current time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the http://au1.php.net/strtotime

Comment: DELETE FROM tablename WHERE timestamp > strtotime("+1 hour")
Would this be correct?

Comment: Your question is very confusing, you appear to have asked for the exact opposite of what you wanted, based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE `timestmap` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Ref:- [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: This is a nice clean solution

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I agree, clean and simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: if you copy and paste the code, watch out for the small typo in "timestamp"

Comment: Oh before I forget, will this still work with form 2013-01-03 20:30:25
? Or does it have to be an actual timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `2013-01-03 20:30:25` is not a timestamp, it is a formatted date. The timestamp for that date would look like this: `1357245025`. You can convert it to a timestamp using the `strtotime` function. You can also work out the timestamp of an hour ago by using `strtotime("-1 hour")` and performing a comparison on the values.

It might be faster just to do all of this within the MySQL query though, MySQL provides queries to do this, using a query similar to the one that `Amit Garg` provided.